# Поиск символа '*'

Tags: python, поиск

Извиняюсь, что задаю два вопроса в день, но нужен ответ, потому что не догадываюсь..
Нужно сделать программу, где пользователь вводит строку, в которой встречается символ 'звездочки' ровно один раз. Программа же определяет порядковый номер 'зведочки'.
Трудность в том, что нельзя использовать метод find и len (for, if, else, elif разрешены). Программы нет, потому что у меня получилось, только используя len.

P.S. Сайт редактирует звездочку другим шрифтом. Звездочка подразумевается использование клавиш Shift + 8

Comment: Используйте `string.index('*')`. К примеру, `print('index * find'.index('*'))` будет `6`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, работает верно :)

Answer (score 0):

Варианты, которые пришли в голову

```
inp = input('Введите текст: ')
```

Через `index()`

```
print(inp.index('*') if '*' in inp else 'Не найдена *')
```

Через `enumerate()`

```
print(next((ix for ix, i in enumerate(inp) if i == '*'), 'Не найдена *'))
```